Qlik Sense not totalling several measures despite being numeric
I have a table with several measures. Only one of them is being totalled in the table:

I have checked the data model viewer and all measures are numeric (and could be summed I asume). However, only the SalesValue is being summed. I checked the measures  in the worksheet and where 'SalesValue' has the option of number formatting, the others only show this option:

Can anyone help me figure out why this happens?
My main load script looks like this (the part about number formatting):

SET ThousandSep='.';
SET DecimalSep=',';
SET MoneyThousandSep='.';
SET MoneyDecimalSep=',';
SET MoneyFormat='€ #.##0,00;€ -#.##0,00';

and this is the load script for these measures:
count(distinct SalesOrderNumber) as OrderCount,
(sum(SalesAmount)) as SalesValue,
(sum(TaxAmt)) as TaxValue,
(sum(SalesAmount - (SalesAmount*(UnitPriceDiscountPct/100)))) as SalesValueIncDiscount,

(sum(if(Manufacturer='Big World Importers', SalesAmount-(SalesAmount*0.35)))) as SalesValueBWI35discount
resident stagedWebSales

the numbers in the data model viewer example look ok:

As these numbers come from a QVD file, I've checked that file too:

Also these numbers look ok.

Ok, figured it out: I've added the measures as a dimension instead of a measure.
Changed it and now it's as expected.
